# What does dialogPath mean when creating a component?

Tags: templates, dialog, components, aem

When I am creating a component there an option in next tab as dialog path .I have added some path of existing dialog in that.When i drag and drop component on page . Not able to edit it as edit option is not coming.

What may be the reason and why is dialogPath used?

[image: Screenshot of Dialog Path]

Answer (score 2):

This is the dialogPath property of the component which is used as a component dialog if the cq:Dialog node is not present under the node (i.e. the node does not have it's own dialog).

It's (one possible) convenient way to reuse common dialog between different components which cannot share common super types (for whatever reasons).

For example, you may want to share RTE dialog box between different components that are technically the same but have to be allowed/disallowed based on business sites.

See the following link for more details: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/components/components-basics.html

> **dialogPath**    String  Path to a dialog; to cover the case when the component does not have a dialog node.

Comment: Tried to replicate but was not working .Do you have any working code?

Comment: Can you explain more on what didn't work. The dialogPath property just invokes the dialog if the cq:dialog node is missing. As en example, I made a component in geometrixx-media project and set the property dialogPath to point to `/apps/geometrixx-media/components/title/dialog` The new component did not have a cq:dialog node in it but editing the properties invoked the dialog from the path above. This is the expected behaviour.